# MYSQL how to add more rows if results are less than a number

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a view so show the most popular questions in the last 2 days.
However because we don't have a lot of activity, it only shows 68 items.
I want to add a way for this statement to say, if results have less than 1000 items, then add the remaining ones without worrying about ranking.

1000 results = 68 popular, 932 regulars

```
SELECT *, ((likesCount*.8)+(commentsCount*.6)+(sharesCount*1)/2.4) as wavg
FROM production.question
    JOIN production.feed
    ON production.question.id = production.feed.q_id
    WHERE (production.feed.timestamp >= (now() - interval 2 day))
GROUP BY production.question.name
ORDER BY wavg DESC
LIMIT 0,1000;
```

(only returns 68 results, need to add the other 932 by just saying SELECT * FROM production.question, or whatever...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want by moving the `where` condition into the `order by` clause.  So, order by the data you want first, and then put the rest.

The following query also replaces the `join` with a `left join`, and includes a match for the second table in the `order by`:

```
SELECT *, ((likesCount*.8)+(commentsCount*.6)+(sharesCount*1)/2.4) as wavg
FROM production.question q LEFT JOIN
     production.feed f
     ON q.id = f.q_id
GROUP BY q.name
ORDER BY (f.timestamp >= (now() - interval 2 day)) desc,
         (f.q_id is not null) desc,
         wavg DESC
LIMIT 0,1000;
```

It also uses table aliases to make a query a bit more readable.

EDIT:

To randomize the questions at the end:

```
ORDER BY (f.timestamp >= (now() - interval 2 day)) desc,
         wavg DESC,
         rand()
LIMIT 0,1000;
```

This won't affect anything where `wavg` is defined, only the "rest" of the records.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I took out the LEFT JOIN left as JOIN for 2 reasons, query is faster and I don't need the f information only r. Is there a way to randomize the questions that are added at the end? 68 + 932 random?